# Conjugate gradient method, intuition for finding the directions.

Tags: optimization, intuition

I was reading [this Quora post](https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-intuitive-explanation-of-what-the-conjugate-gradient-method-is) to understand a bit what is behind the conjugated gradient algorithm. In the long answer it is said :

> “If we move in a direction until the directional derivative in that
> direction is zero (equivalently, the gradient is orthogonal to the
> direction we are traveling) then the minimum falls somewhere on the
> plane orthogonal to our direction!”

So if we know the directions $d_k$ could we actually find the coefficient $\alpha_k$ by solving something like

\begin{equation}
\langle\Lambda^{1/2}Q \operatorname{grad}(x_k+\alpha_kd_k),\Lambda^{1/2}Qd_k\rangle=0
\end{equation}

because we would ask the scalar product to be $0$ inside space where the level sets of the function to optimize are spherical. I am not sure how to show we get the same result.

Comment: I don't think I understand the expression $ \mathrm{grad}(x_k + \alpha_k d_k) $.  With respect to what variable is the gradient taken?

Comment: @JakeMirra, sorry, I wanted to say $\operatorname{grad}f(x_k+\alpha_kd_k)$, the gradient of the cost function evaluated in the point $x_k+\alpha_kd_k$

Comment: note that the statement is for a quadratic function, so you can fill in the formula for the gradient